# Receiving JSON Dics with python

Tags: python, json

I'm pretty new to python and i want to get a JSON dic and  make an python dic based on it.
An exemple of those JSON dics is this: 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=2.0&q=python?cod=&start=2

So i need to get it and print all the keys "URL" on the screen.

I have seen some things like this but did not worked good, my code now is:

```
    while (page < 50):
    page_src = urllib.urlopen(search_url + '?cod=&start=' + str(page)).read()
    json_src = json.loads (page_src)

    for item in json_src['responseData']:
        sub_item = json_src['responseData']['results']
        for link in sub_item:
            for key in link:
                if (key == u'"url"'):
                    print link[key]
    page = page + 1
```

But when executed i get:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

IDK where i'm wrong, please help me..
Thank you all guys.

TheV0iD

Comment: I have seen that the code on stack overflow is without some identation oO, but here its normal. pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BRafWptP

Comment: First: if you get an error, *show us the whole error message*. Traceback and all. Second, are you sure the JSON looks the way you think it does? Perhaps it has nulls where you're expecting something else.

Answer (score 1):

Check out to make sure your url is correct, the code worked for me. My only revision would be:

```
for item in json_src['responseData']['results']:
    print link[key]
```

Also, make sure your starting and ending values of `page` are real urls, you are getting the NoneType because there was no such thing as `'responseData'` found.

Also what is your value of search_url? are you including the `?v=2.0&q=python?` in it? if you messed up your url at all your NoneType is coming from trying to iterate through `json_src['responseData']['results']` because there is no such thing.

EDIT:

The issue is that you reassign the search_url in the loop. The second iteration the url becomes `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=2.0&q=python?cod=&start=0?cod=&start=1` with both appended. Simple change the `search_url =` to `cur_url =`

Final code:

```
print "\n\n RESULTS:"
while (page < 2):
    current_url = search_url + '?cod=&start=' + str(page)
    json_src = json.load(urllib.urlopen(search_url))
    print json_src
    results = json_src['responseData']['results']
    for result in results:
        print "\t" + result['url']
    page = page + 1
```

Comment: search_url is correct bro :/

Comment: Post the full error, what line is it al?

Comment: its the url. Check the edit

Comment: Worked now, thank you a lot, with this i can finally finish my application.